# Denial of installation WIX Installer

Tags: installation, wix

I made a bootstrapper (bootstrapper is an installer that contains other installers to put all together, in this case will be my app and SQL Express database installer). When I start the bootstrapper, the SQL Express installation window  is being displayed on the screen and if I close the window, my app is still set, and I need if user closes SQL Express installation window then my program won't be installed.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany AboutUrl="https://mycompany.ru/"
         Copyright="ol raits rezervit" UpgradeCode="1788BF21-18BD-49E8-A572-DD38F9B67A88">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"
                         Result="exists" Variable="SQLExpressInstalled_x64" Win64="yes"/>
    <Chain>
      <ExePackage SourceFile="SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe" DetectCondition="SQLExpressInstalled_x64" Permanent="no"></ExePackage>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="MyProgram.msi"></MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would adding "Vital" be a usable suggestion for you?
I have added this suggestion in your provided code example as the last argument for the ExePackage.

**"Vital"**
Specifies whether the package must succeed for the chain to continue. The default "yes" indicates that if the package fails then the chain will fail and rollback or stop. If "no" is specified then the chain will continue even if the package reports failure.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany AboutUrl="https://mycompany.ru/ "Copyright="ol raits rezervit" UpgradeCode="1788BF21-18BD-49E8-A572-DD38F9B67A88">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server"
                         Result="exists" Variable="SQLExpressInstalled_x64" Win64="yes"/>
    <Chain>
      <ExePackage SourceFile="SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe" DetectCondition="SQLExpressInstalled_x64" Permanent="no" Vital="yes"></ExePackage>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="MyProgram.msi"></MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Ref - https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html